# Changing day night mode dynamically in android

Tags: android

I am working on an Android based GPS Navigation application and it is necessary to implement automatic day and night theme switcher for the application based on the light sensor values. The problem is I have to change the theme without restarting the Activity or the application.

I tried to achieve this by following this tutorial (http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/runtime-theme-change/) where custom states are used to change between day and night mode. But it requires lot of changes as my application has many layouts. Also with this implementation developers have to take care of Day and Night modes for future screens.

Is there any simple and effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you apply any kind of filter to the light sensor values? I'm working on something similar, just curious.

Comment: Yes. I was reading the sensor value on sensor value change for every 1 or 2 second and finding mean value of 20 observations. If this mean is greater than a threshold value then I changed the color

Comment: Have you tried night and notnight qualifer values for layouts ? Like mentioned in this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164414/11158194

Answer (score 2):

[ViewFlipper!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) This is what I use in my applications to allow the user the option of day or night themes. Also because of the nature of java it can be changed based on any boolean value (i.e. if light is darker than it was 2 seconds go). That being said, there is no real easy way to automatically make all your layouts switch without coding for the switch or building on someone else's work.

Here's how:

I have an application that has 1 activity, 1 layout, and a button to switch the colors.

- MainActivity.java
- activity_main.xml (contains button)

a ViewFlipper is placed as every layouts  child element like so: (every layout that needs both day and night mode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then for each layout I make Day Time colored layout and Night Time Colored Layout

Both Day and Night layouts must be children of the ViewFlipper so if you collapse both layouts it should be

- < ViewFlipper>

  - < RelativeLayout> **Day elements go in here** < /RelativeLayout>
  - < RelativeLayout> **Night Elements go in here** < /RelativeLayout>
- < /ViewFlipper>

Here comes the hassle: Each element must have a unique id because they are in the same document, if you want a day button and night button on the same screen for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ViewFlipper
  android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DayLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileDayBtn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NightLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/profileNightBtn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's it for the layouts, now to actually change it:

inside every activity that has a Day or Night Layout add this code: (I added mine to the onCreate of every activity but this wont do for a switch based on time)

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button dayBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profileDayBtn);
    Button nightBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profileNightBtn);

    View.OnClickListener changeColorMode = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.viewFlipper );
          if (v == dayBtn) {
            vf.showNext();
          } else if (v == nightBtn) {
            vf.showPrevious();
          }
    };
    dayBtn.setOnClickListener(changeColorMode);
    nightBtn.setOnClickListener(changeColorMode);
    }
```

layout was set to activity_main but because activity_main has a viewflipper, it set it to the **first root** (index 0) inside the viewflipper (which was my day layout), .showNext() will show the next root element (index 1 my night layout and so on if I added more)

to close, if you need a specific layout shown instead of guessing with .showNext() you can call

```
   viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(XXX));
```

Where XXX can be replaced with the index (0, 1, ect) of the layout or XXX may be replaced with the specific layout id like this
   `viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.DayLayout));`

This is what i use and it works great because its very simple to understand and is very customizable! Hope this helps

-Stephen

Answer (score 0):

No, theme/styles must be applied before you create the view/layout.

So if you want to change the them runtimely, you have to do everything in JAVA code like setBackground(color) setImageRes(xxx) setTextColor(xxx)