# Splash Screen Based on time of Day

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable, android-styles

Is it possible to have a different splash screen based on the time of day. I have tried to create values-night/styles.xml and values-notnight/styles.xml along with a drawable-night and drawable-notnight with same named images, but it is not alternating based on the time of the phone.

Does anyone have experience with having different launch screens without using a timer in the main activity?

Thus, doing a launch screen only until the main activity is loaded.

Am I missing a setup step?

values-notnight/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/metalic</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
        <!-- Optional, on Android 5+ you can modify the colorPrimaryDark color to match the windowBackground color for further branding-->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item> -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

values-notnight/styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/carbon</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    <!-- Optional, on Android 5+ you can modify the colorPrimaryDark color to match the windowBackground color for further branding-->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item> -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

drawable-notnight/launch_screen.xml

```
<!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/carbon"/>
<!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
<item>
    <bitmap

        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleHeight="60%"
        android:scaleWidth="60%"/>


</item>
```

drawable-night/launch_screen.xml

```
<!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/metalic"/>
<!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
<item>
    <bitmap

        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleHeight="60%"
        android:scaleWidth="60%"/>


</item>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.root.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/tech"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/tech"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In case you fetch the time from your phone correctly, of course you can launch a different splashScreen based on that information. For example by defining seperate Splash classes with corresponding layouts

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I added the code, currently it is defaulting to the drawable-notnight code even though the time on my phone has manually been set to 23:46.

Comment: Does my manifest need an extra persmission?

Answer (score 0):

Three things you have to do

**First:** For day, folder name will be `values` and for night, folder name will be `values-night`. Drawable accordingly `drawable` and `drawable-night`.

**Second:**
Use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` as parent theme.

**Third:** Use [ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731198/changing-day-night-mode-dynamically-in-android/31388848#31388848) in your layout

In your code 
Find the current time and check with expected time:

```
  ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.viewFlipper );
  if (mCurrentTime == //whatever time you want) {
        vf.showNext();
  }
```

Comment: I did these changes and my time on my device is 10:05 pm, but it is still showing the day mode. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: ViewFlipper will not work for splash screen as the splash screen occurs from the manifest, before the layout is selected by the activity.